# Model Binding not working with mvc1

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have class

```
public class Class2
{
    public string myName { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public jInformation jf { get; set; }
    public Class2()
    {

    }
}

public class jInformation
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string display { get; set; }
    public jInformation()
    {

    }
}
```

Now my action method is

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {
        Class2 oClass = new Class2();
        return View("ViewPage1",oClass);
    }
```

And post is

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public void Test(Class2 oClass)
    {
        String sTemp = oClass.myName;
        String sp = oClass.phone;
    }
```

I want to create a stongley typed view with ViewContent As "Edit". So when i create strongly typed view, it just create text box for myName and phone property. How can i create textbox for jINformation class? I am using MVC1 and newbie to MVC world.......

My CustomModel Binder looks like

```
  public class Class2ModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        return new Class2()
                   {
                       myName = request.Form.Get("myName"),
                       phone = request.Form.Get("phone"),
                       jf = new jInformation { name = request.Form.Get("name"), display = request.Form.Get("display") }
                   };
    }
}
```

I registered it with application_start. Now question is, what i should pass on get and post method?

Comment: Just altered my answer, to show you how the controller looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous comment was a bit wrong. The default Model Binder will work for your 'Class2'.

Here i tested and it works.

## The Controller code

```
public class TestController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexPost()
    {
        Class2 cls = new Class2();
        UpdateModel(cls);
        return View(cls);
    }
}
```

## The view code (Just a form against your Model)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Class2>" %>
<h2>Index</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("indexpost","test")) {%>
<%: Html.TextBox("myName") %>
<%: Html.TextBox("phone")%>
<%: Html.TextBox("jf.name")%>
<%: Html.TextBox("jf.display")%>


<input type="Submit" value="submit" />
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the name property of the jInformation class with the folowing textbox:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("jf.name")%>
```

This assumes your model class for the view is Class2. With the dot notation (jf.name) you can access the child object. This will modelbind, just tested it.

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new Class2());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Class2 class2)
        {
            return View(class2);
        }
```

View:

Answer (score -1):

You have your own class 'jInformation' in your Model class 'class2'.
The MVC default binder will only work with standard datatypes (ie. int, string etc.). It will not bind your type.

If you want to bind your own type you will have to write your own binder.

Comment: I am  trying to get all values on post method and i don't want to use formValueCollection

Comment: This is not true, the modelbinder is capable of binding nested classes in your viewmodel

Comment: i have added Custom Modelbinder

Comment: hi robin, can you explain how?

Comment: See my answer. If you generate a strongly typed view with visual studio, no form elements are rendered automatically for child classes. you have to type the textbox helper yourself. Use the textbox as shown in my example.